# How to download remote repository to local on Github desktop?

Tags: git, github-for-windows, github-desktop

One of my friend gave me a git link like this :

`git@123.123.123.123:/home/git/project.git`

along with username and password.

`username: git`
`password: 123456!@#$%^`

I'm trying to a `get latest` (similar to Download zip on github public repo), I have a Github desktop (for Windows) installed but have no idea how to achieve this. I search and read the documentation online but it's confusing and I'm getting mixed answer.

Any help will be appreciated.
Apologize for bad english.

Comment: You want to download a copy of the project to your local ?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Never done it with the github-desktop ...but ,  if you want to do it from terminal check this out https://git-scm.com/videos

Comment: Personally,I found Github desktop more confusing than helpful.  It was worth learning the Git bash command line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it would be easier to clone the repo using git bash:
`git clone git@123.123.123.123:/home/git/project.git`

PS you can run git bash from GitHub for Windows.